# How to block an intent from an activity?

Tags: android-intent

I am starting an activity through an intent on button click of main activity but i want to get result of that activity and then call another function in main activity which uses that result. The issue i am facing is this that whenever startactivity(i) is called the compiler also called the function which is written right after startactivity(i).

My code is as follows:

```
public void bt_Open(View v)
{
    Intent i= new Intent(Map.this,FileChooser.class);
    startActivity(i);

        m_GisRenderer.m_Project.load_file(AppFuncs.path);
```

}

What i want is that first startActivity(i) is called then after that activity has finished its working then load file function should be called

Comment: use finish() after startActivity(i);

Comment: but that will end the main activity

Comment: load this m_GisRenderer.m_Project.load_file(AppFuncs.path); in next activity inside onCreate()  .. try this :)

Comment: no i want load file func to be called with in main activity i want this func to be called right after intent activity is finished.

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult` and do the work in `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. I have used setactivity for result and then called the required functionality.